# node.js - cannot access variables of outer callback from inner callback

Tags: node.js

In my discord bot, I have some code that looks something like this (with portions impertinent to the question omitted):

```
run(message) {
    [...]

    mongoClient.connect(config.mongodb.url, function(err, db) {
        [...]

        var roleMessage = `\`\`\`Roles on ${message.guild.name} (use !role:add <role> to assign them):`
        var isNotificationsEnabled = false

        db.collection('roles').find({"sid": message.guild.id}).each(function (err, doc) {
            [...]

            if(doc) {
                if(doc.rolename != '$notify') {
                    roleMessage += `${doc.rolename}\n`
                } else {
                    isNotificationsEnabled = true
                }
            } else {
                [...]
            }
        })

        [...]
    })
}
```

My problem is that variables from the `mongoClient.connect()` callback are inaccessible from within the inner callback (specifically `roleMessage` and `isNotificationsEnabled`) - I'm trying to build a string out of database elements in a MongoDB database. Is there any way I can make these variables accessible, or is there a better way of doing things?

Thanks in advance for anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with javascript you can see the example below related to scope access to variables,

```
let message = { some: 'thing' }
let items = [ 'item1', 'item2' ]
let something = message => {

     let newvar = 'scope1';
      items.forEach(function(item) {
        items.forEach(function(item2) {
        console.log(item2 + ' ' + item + ' ' + newvar + ' ' + message.some)
        })
      })

}

something(message)
```

> db.collection('roles').find({"sid": message.guild.id}).each(function (err, doc) {

May not be returning any data from the collection.

Comment: It's returning data from the collection - I have personally verified this beforehand. The symptoms that my code is exhibiting would suggest that the outer variables are inaccessible within the inner callback.